# React Native codificar con el modelo de clases

Tags: reactjs, poo, react-native, clase, uml

Como puedo seguir el modelo orientado a objetos con el diagrama de clases en uml, y programar con React Native, si para codificar usamos actualmente solo funciones. De que forma puedo representar mi modelo de clases pero ahora con mi código de react native con funciones, sabiendo que tienen estado y puedo declarar variables y métodos dentro de mi función.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, en React puedes transformar componentes funcionales a [componentes con paradigma POO](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class), no estoy seguro de si esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones, pero sería bueno que agregaras algo de código de lo que has intentado, de lo contrario la pregunta puede ser cerrada, saludos.

Comment: Usa react con typescript, este es orientado a objetos. Lo haces como cualquier lenguaje orientado a objeto con typescript, para renderizar react usa funciones que es my aparte, solo crea objetos dentro de el componente funcional tienes el useRef.

Comment: Mil gracias la guia